# How do I regain my budgies' trust after they have been suddenly forced into a new cage?

Tags: birds, cage, new-pets, budgerigar, habitat

My family recently got five budgies, two males and three females. They get along fairly well, and were soon tame enough to eat from our hands. They would walk/fly around the room and come to our feet whenever we came into the room. A few weeks later, we got a new cage for them to live in, as the old one was too small.

Today, my mom moved most of their "furniture" (food, toys, etc.) into a bigger, new cage, then lured them into it with millet. She then shut the cage's door on them to "help them get used to it." The rest of my family, me included, were completely against this and we wanted to introduce the budgies to the new cage slowly, without forcing them into a new living situation suddenly. Now, the budgies scoot away from my hand and they won't move from their spots. One of them releases (is that the right word) watery poop and fluffs up her feathers when I come near, and she looks stressed and scared.

How can we regain their trust?

Comment: Welcome to Pets SE, and apologies that you didn't get a quick response to your question. My advice would be to give them time, but given the dates on this question, you might already know whether that works and how long it took for them to adjust. Maybe you could draft your own answer? Hope your budgies all adjusted and are fine in their new cage.